# Get list of calls to a method and arguments passed with the call from source code

Tags: ruby, parsing

**Question**

Given the following code, I want to extract `muffinize` and all the arguments passed with it **without running the code**:

```
$ask = false
muffinize("Shoop")
muffinize("Woop") if($ask == true)
if($ask == false)
  muffinize("Pants")
end
```

This is the output that I would expect:

```
Call#:Args
1:"Shoop"
2:"Woop"
3:"Pants"
```

**What I'm doing so far**

I'm parsing the source code with [Ripper](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/ripper/rdoc/Ripper.html) to find the locations where the method is called. Then I'm finding the range of characters in the line of code where the method is called. After extracting the method from the line, I'm then analyzing it with the [Parser](https://github.com/whitequark/parser) gem. I will post the code as an answer once I've complete it, but I'm interested in hearing if there's a better way to do this. I don't know code parsing that well so I'm kind of flailing around blindly at this point.

**Why not just use a Regex**

A regex would still capture commented code blocks. There's probably other corner cases that I haven't considered yet.

Comment: I was not familiar with Ripper.  It looks pretty interesting.  Peter Cooper talks about it [here](http://www.rubyinside.com/using-ripper-to-see-how-ruby-is-parsing-your-code-5270.html), in conjuction with the 'awesome_print' gem.  I do have a question: do you not want to run the code merely because it would not show all potential calls to muffinize()?  (For example, it would not flag "Woop" in your example.)

Comment: That is precisely why I do not want to run the code. I do not have 100% test coverage.

Comment: What about `self.send("muffin" + "ize", "FooBar")`? In the end, it will become aparent, that you generally can't (reliably) statically analyze a dynamic language without actually running the code and tracing it.

Comment: @HolgerJust I would accept that as answer and concede that my use case is an anomaly and is of little use to this site.

Comment: Still don't understand the downvote though. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Seanny123 Some people just downvote questions (and answers) they think are actually impossible to answer without providing explanations. That said, generally it would have been a good idea to include at least some rough code into your question to have something to discuss about without guessing. Also, questions asking for how a general concept can be tackled are often off-topic on SO because they tend to lead to broad subjective discussions and most of the time contain too little information to be conclusively answered (yours is borderline okay in my eyes).

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep those things in mind next time I post a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, it's is hard (read: impossible) to statically analyze a programm written in a dynamic language like Ruby, i.e. find all possible method calls or branches without actually running the program. The reason for that is that dynamic languages like Ruby (but also others like Python, Perl or nowadays to some extend even Java or .NET) allow to dynamically generate method calls based on data in the running program. An example would be this

```
def deliciousness(pastry)
  self.send("#{pastry}ize", "Icing")
end

deliciousness("muffin")
```

This code will call the `muffinize` method and pass `"Icing"` as a parameter. However, as the actual name of the called method is mentioned nowhere in the source code, you have no way to know that using only a static analyzer or parser. You can make that example arbitrarily more complex and also involve code generation and way more layers of indirection. My point is, you can't be sure you get everything, even if you specifically cover some additional cases.

What you can do however is to trace your code as it is actually run (possibly via tests) and find possible invocations of your method. You be sure to ind all of them using static analysis. And once you use e.g. any web framework, you are definitely out of luck due to the large amount of meta-programming and code-generation involved.

Answer (score -1):

Although Holger Just is entirely correct, for me I have a use case where no one would ever call the method without explicitly typing it out. It is a bizarre corner case, but I thought I would share my solution anyways. Here is the code I ended up using:

```
require "parser/current"
require "ripper"

#Get the source code somehow
code = Ripper.lex(source)
callNumber = 0
code.each_with_index do |line, index|
    if(line[1] == :on_ident and line[2][/^muffinize$/] != nil)
        extractedCode = ""
        charEnd = 0
        lineSperated = nil
        charStart = line[0][1]
        lineNumber = line[0][0]
        #Look ahead till you find the first right parenthese
        i = 0
        while(i < code.length-1)
            if(code[index+i] != nil)
                if(code[index+i][1] == :on_rparen)
                    charEnd = code[index+i][0][1]
                    break
                end
            end
            i += 1
        end
        lineSeperated = source.split(/\n/)
        extractedCode = lineSeperated[lineNumber-1]
        extractedCode = extractedCode[charStart,(charEnd-charStart+1)]
        #Use the somewhat crazy Ruby parser gem to interpret the code as the Ruby interpreter would interpret it.
        callArray = Parser::CurrentRuby.parse(extractedCode).to_a
        text = callArray[2].to_a[0].to_s
        callNumber += 1
        puts "#{callNuber}:#{text}"
    end
end
```